# HTML buttons: Code-behind operation

Tags: asp.net

Earlier, I had a button control on my web page. but now I changed it to a CSS button suting my needs. Before this, the button control was performing code-behind operation but now I switched to this CSS button.

```
<a href="" title="" class="">Delete profile</a>
```

How can I accomplish the same code-behind process now?

Comment: Are you trying to access the control server-side? If so, you'll need to include runat="server"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the anchor to be a server side control (turning it to a [`HtmlAnchor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlanchor.aspx) control) and use the [`ServerClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlanchor.serverclick.aspx) event:

```
<a href="" title="" class="" id="cssButton" runat="server">Delete profile</a>
```

Comment: Previously, I was using Ajax Confirm extender on Button Control, how can I apply the Confirm Extender to the < a href > ?

Answer (score 2):

To keep it simple, you could use a linkbutton and get the server side click event

```
   <asp:LinkButton ID="lb1" runat="server" onclick="lb1_Click" CssClass="cssClass" />
```